# Trying to locate some objects in a space

Tags: symfony, twig, distance

I'm trying to locate some objects in a field using Twig given some conditions (yes, I know it s simple, but I'm having too much troubles to have results). It's all right, but I'm having troubles giving some distance between objects.

This is my code:

```
{% for key, positions in teams %}
    {% for key1, position in positions %}
        {% for key2, player in  position %}
            {% set x = 100 %}
            {% set counter = player.positionId|length + 1%}
            {% set d = x/counter %}
            {% if player.positionId == 1 %}
                {% set top = 0.4 %}
                {% set xpos = 42 %} //That value is correct because it's a goalkeeper
            {% elseif player.positionId == 2%}
                {% set top  = 9.5 %}
                {% set xpos =  %}
            {% elseif player.positionId == 3%}
                {% set top = 20.5 %}
                {% set xpos = %}
            {% elseif player.positionId == 4%}
                {% set top = 32.5 %}
                {% set xpos = %}
            {% endif %}
```

In summary, I have some players that are located on different y-coodinates given their positions, but also I need each one to have some distance between them if they have the same position, being xpos its position in the x-axis.

If you don't know Twig, you can help me using another lannguage too. Thanks in advance
Ah, and well, I want to know how to separate the teams (because it renders all players at this moment)

Comment: In general I would suggest to use PHP or similar to do this. Normally you shouldn't do this in templates.

Comment: Sadly I'm a novice and if it is more convenient to do using php, how I can pass the values to Twig?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to pass values to twig, one way is to do this through routing,

```
# app/config/routing.yml
blog_show:
    path:      /blog/{YOUR_VARIABLE_OR_VALUE_HERE}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

see this reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

you can also set global variables: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

or create an array in controller using repository or on your on, then send this to the view through the params 
ie)

```
$repository2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME_Bundle:YOUR_REPOSITORY');
        $YOUR_ARRAY_NAME = $repository2->REPOSITORY_METHOD_OR_GENERIC_METHOD($IDENTIFIER);

$params = array('form' => $form->createView(), 'YOUR_ARRAY_NAME' => $YOUR_ARRAY_NAME');
            return $this->render('SystemCheckoutBundle:Checkout:checkout.html.twig', $params);
```

these params can then be accessed in the view via:

```
{% for YOUR_ARRAY_NAME in YOUR_ARRAY_NAME %}
               Client ID: {{ YOUR_ARRAY_NAME.contactId }}<br>
               First Name: {{ YOUR_ARRAY_NAME.firstName }}<br>
               Last Name:{{ YOUR_ARRAY_NAME.lastName }}<br>
               Email: {{ YOUR_ARRAY_NAME.email }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```